# FATAL ERROR php - unexpected ')'

Tags: php

this code gives me the error :

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' on line number 10 -- line 10 is this one: "if  ( ! empty( EMPTY ) ) { "

I don't get it...could you help explaining?

```
define('CONSTANT', 1);

define('_CONSTANT', 0);

define('EMPTY','');

if  ( ! empty( EMPTY ) ) {

    if ( ! ( ( boolean ) _CONSTANT ) ) {

        print "One";

    }

} else if ( constant( 'CONSTANT' == 1 )) {

    print "TWO";

}
```

Comment: `empty` checks variables, not constants. If you want to check if a constant exists, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Answer (score 5):

In PHP method names are case-insensitive. For example, these statements are doing the same thing:

```
echo empty(0);
//out: 1
echo emPTY(0);
//out: 1
echo EMPTY(0);
//out: 1
```

You are trying to define a constant that has the same name as built-in PHP method `empty`. When you call `empty(EMPTY)` (which is the same as `empty(empty)` PHP thinks that you are trying to call (outer) `empty` on result of (inner) `EMPTY` invocation, but oops, your inner `EMPTY` is not a method invocation at all (it misses the braces). During building AST PHP expects something like `empty(EMPTY(...))` (note the open brace after inner `EMPTY`) and that's why you are getting syntax error `expecting "("...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defined` because `empty` check variables and you are checking on constants. `defined` — Checks whether a given named constant exists.
As its said here [defined Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)